# How to use .split() to extract HH,MM,SS separately from a 1970-1-1T00:00:00Z and get "00" instead of "0"

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, split

I have a netcdf file containing time in the format `1970-1-1T00:00:00Z`. I need to extract the hour, minute and seconds using `split()`. I tried as follows, but it didn't work as expected.

```
hour = int(nc['time'].units.split(' ')[2].split('-')[2][8])
print(hour)
     0
```

Does anybody have a solution to do this?

Comment: Why don't you use the `datetime` module to parse the time?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Isn't the hour 0?

Comment: hour should be 00, not just 0

Comment: 00 is the same number as 0. Do you want a string `'00'`? Then don't convert to `int()`.

Comment: *"I need ... using `split()`"*: are you sure you don't want to look at other -- possibly better -- options? Why this constraint?

Comment: Its best to post a working, minimal example. The `nc['time'].units` isn't important for the example. How about a hardcoded value that we can use to test?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes I wanted the string `00`. Oops! I completely forget about the `int()`. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The only reason you need `00` is for display purposes. Unless or until you need to display the date, there is no harm storing it as the *integer* 0.

Comment: @chepner Right. It is just a display purpose.

Comment: `i = 0; print(f'{i:02}')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first split by the `'T'` to get the time part, then split again by the `:` to get the hours, minutes, and seconds:

```
t = '1970-1-1T00:00:00Z'
(hour, minute, seconds) = t.split('Z')[0].split('T')[1].split(':')
print(hour, minute, seconds)
```

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression:

```
import re

t = '1970-1-1T00:00:00Z'
(hour, minute, seconds) = re.findall(r'T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})', t)[0]
print(hour, minute, seconds)
```

Comment: That is a neat split() solution. Helpful. But how can I escape the `Z` when printing seconds?

Comment: @linux_lover I've edited my answer to work for seconds too. Keeping true to the `.split()`, you can just do `t.split('Z')[0]` to get rid of the `Z`. Alternatively, you could have `t[:-1]` because there's nothing after the `Z`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.replace` before using `str.split`.

```
>>> "1970-1-1T00:00:00Z".replace('Z', '').split('T')[1].split(':')
['00', '00', '00']
```

You can `re.findall`.

```
h, m, s = re.findall(r"T(\d+):(\d+):(\d+).*$", "1970-1-1T00:00:00Z")[0]
print(h, m, s)
# 00 00 00
```

Explanation:

- `T` matches the character `"T"`.
- `(\d+)` is a capturing group that matches one or more digits.
- `:` matches the character `":"`.
- `.*` matches zero or more of any character.
- `$` matches the end of the line.